# lessc not compiling on osx

Tags: css, node.js, macos, less

I have installed less from npm (sudo npm install -g less).

Version 2.6.1

When I try to compile a .less file, I have not results

I write:

> lessc mylessfile.less destination.css

The "destination.css" file is not created

If I write:

> lessc mylessfile.less

It not show me the .less file in console.

I am using OSX 10.11.4

Can you help me please?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I risolved.
The problem was the version of node (6.0.0)
Now I installed the version 4.4.4 and now is working fine

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Node 6.0.0 and 6.1.1 gave that problem. I was using node 5.x and there was no problem. Then i just bought new mac, installing latest 6.1.0, and face the same problem.

I tried to install 4.4.4 LTS, and the problem is solved.

Comment: Yes, with the 4.4.4 version is working fine all.
Also the debug node with WebStorm not worked with 6.0.0 version of node (I intercepted the breakpoint but Webstorm not showed me the values of variables) but with the 4.4.4 its all is working